# Permissions for 'Sites' folder (apache) are wrong

Tags: macos, command-line, permissions, apache-http-server, user-groups

My head is a bit mashed over this.

I have moved from MAMP to using Mac's own AMP stack, and have got it working, but just CANNOT get the directory permissions right.

My localhost points to `~/Sites` and my username appears to be `user` (in that in the terminal is shows up as `user at MacBookPro in ~ $`). I also seem to have a group called `staff`.

I have checked that the user group is set in `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` (about line 120) as 
    `User _www
    Group _www`

### The Problem:

Whenever I try and access a URL like `localhost/_Projects/fresh2/public/index.php` I get a 403 Forbidden error. (This would be the path to my Laravel project).

It looks like I have the *opposite* of what I want set up, as I can easily see into the `localhost/_Projects/fresh2/app/config/` directory and see all these files as a directory listing in my browser, but the one folder that I would expect to see (`public') isn't there (I'm guessing this is down to the permissions).

NOTE: When I run a 'server' via Command line `php artisan serve` within this Laravel project then I can run the project's index.php and it works at I would expect the app to work, with no permission issues. (But I also use this folder to house other PHP apps (like Codeigniter) so I need to access it via a URL)

### Folder Permissions

I have run  `ls -l` within the root of this project folder and this is what I see:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 16 user  _www    544 24 Jan 13:19 .
drwxr-x---+  5 user  _www    170 24 Jan 18:50 ..
-rw-r--r--+  1 user  _www     11 19 Jan 02:14 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--+  1 user  _www    103 19 Jan 02:14 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--+  1 user  _www    145 19 Jan 02:14 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-xr-x+ 14 user  _www    476 19 Jan 02:14 app
-rwxr-xr-x+  1 user  _www   2451 19 Jan 02:14 artisan
drwxr-xr-x+  5 user  _www    170 19 Jan 02:14 bootstrap
drwxr-xr-x+  7 user  _www    238 24 Jan 13:19 components
-rw-r--r--+  1 user  _www    787 24 Jan 13:19 composer.json
-rw-r--r--+  1 user  _www  64982 24 Jan 13:20 composer.lock
-rw-r--r--+  1 user  _www    566 19 Jan 02:14 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x+  7 user  _www    238 19 Jan 02:14 public
-rw-r--r--+  1 user  _www   1795 19 Jan 02:14 readme.md
-rw-r--r--+  1 user  _www    519 19 Jan 02:14 server.php
drwxr-xr-x+ 27 user  _www    918 24 Jan 13:20 vendor
```

What might I be doing wrong? What other info can I provide?

Comment: I have given up and just used the standard webroot (/Library/WebServer/Documents/_Projects). It all seems to be working fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give ownership to apache user for all files. Here the apache user is `_www` and try. Use `chown` for changing ownership. The command will look like something below.

`chown _www:_www -R fldername`. Here the folder might be the `DocumentRoot` of your project.